# Push Notifications working with iPhone development provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone

I have my development app installed on my iPhone with the development provisioning profile. Do push notifications work with the development provisioning profile, or only on distribution?

I'm curious because push notifications are working just fine on distribution, but not with the development app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work with the devel profile. There's a sandbox service. (See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

Comment: Do I need a separate .pem file for push notifications to work with development profile?

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Push notification will work only if the provisioning profile contains the key `aps-environment` (the value is either `production` or `development`). The team provisioning profile (with the wildcard) can't be used with push notifications, therefore will not contain the `aps-environment` key/value entry. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html) that explains creating the necessary certificates.